# Convergence in a product of $p$-adic groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, p-adic-groups

Does the following statement hold?

Let $p$ be a rational prime. For each $x\in\prod_{\ell}{\mathbb Z}_{\ell}$, there exist a natural number $M_x$ such that $x$ lies in the closure of $\{e_1p^{n_1}+e_2p^{n_2}+\cdots+e_{M_x}p^{n_{M_x}}: \text{$n_i\ge 0$ and $e_i\in\{-1,0,1\}$ for each $i$}\}$ in $\prod_{\ell} {\mathbb Z}_{\ell}$.

If it does not                         hold, what if we only consider those $x\in\prod_{\ell}{\mathbb Z}_{\ell}$ whose component at $p$ is zero?

Comment: If this is true for every $x$ in $\prod_{\ell} \mathbb{Z}_\ell$ then it is certainly true for every $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Now take $p=5$ and $x=2$ and you'll see that it is not possible.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. In fact, my statement is trivially true for every $x\in{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: what is the unreadable character before $n_i$? Can you write it in LaTeX?

Comment: The character is just a colon ":" and is readable to me.
The set whose closure is considered is $\{e_1p^{n_1}+e_2p^{n_2}+\cdots+e_{M_x}p^{n_{M_x}}: \text{$n_i\ge 0$ and $e_i\in\{-1,0,1\}$ for each $i$}\}$

Comment: I meant the unreadable character after the colon -- the unicode character F728 which, on further investigation, has not been assigned a symbol yet and hence may just not be showing up at all on your browser (I can see it on mine as a random box with some numbers in). Let's forget that and go back to the $p=5$ and $x=2$ question. Are you allowing some of the $n_i$ to be the same?

Comment: Yes, $n_i$ could be all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is negative and we can tell this just by looking at $\mathbb Z_p$.

For each $M$, the set of sums of $\leq M$ terms of the form $\pm p^n$ for arbitrary nonnegative $n$ is closed in $\mathbb Z_p$. Because convolutions of closed sets are closed, it is sufficient to prove this for $\{\pm p^n\} \cup \{0\}$, where it is obvious - $\{0\}$ is the only limit point of $\{\pm p^n\}$.

So the union over all $M$ of the closure of this set is simply the union over all $M$ of this set and hence consists only (and exactly) of integers.

---

The answer to the second question is also negative. Numbers of the form  $e_i p^{n_i}$ can take at most $2k+1$ possible values modulo $p^k-1$, as the value only depends on $e_i$ and $n$ mod $k$. Hence sums of $M$ terms of that type can only take at most $(2k+1)^M$ values modulo $p^{k}-1$. The set elemeents in $\prod_{\ell\neq p} \mathbb Z_\ell$ that lie in a given residue class is closed, so the closure of the set of sums of $M$ terms of that type has measure at most $\frac{(2k+1)^M}{p^{k}-1}$. Taking $k$ to $\infty$, it has measure $0$ in $\prod_{\ell\neq p} \mathbb Z_\ell$.

Hence the union over all $M$ also has measure $0$ in $\prod_{\ell\neq p} \mathbb Z_\ell$.

Comment: The measure theory part of the argument can be replaced by an appeal to the Baire category theorem. Nice choice of the modulus, though.

Comment: @Fan It is incorrect that $\{0\}$ is the only limit point of $\{\pm p^n: n\ge 0 \}$. In fact, the sequence $(p^{n!})_{n\ge 0}$ converges to something not in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Tony It is the only limit point in $\mathbb Z_p$. In $\prod_ell \mathbb Z_\ell$ $0$ is not the only limit point, I agree.

Comment: @Tony Though my comment mainly refers to the second question, it also applies to the first one, so it suffices to show that there is no $M$ that works for all $x$ uniformly on an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and I guess you can choose $V=\{(\dots 1010\cdots10**\dots*)_p\}$, where there are enough 10's to outnumber $M$, and the *'s are chosen so that $V$ lies in $U$.